# Connecting page for PSQL and PHP

Tags: php, postgresql

**pgconnect.php**

```
<?php

    $db_connection = pg_connect("host=localhost dbname=postgres user=postgres password=postgres");

    if ($db_connection) {   

    echo 'Connection attempt succeeded.';   

    } else {   

    echo 'Connection attempt failed.';   

    }   
?>
```

This is my pgconnect.php page. I am getting an **Internal server 500 error**. I am not able to figure out the issue with this code. It would be great if someone could help me out.

Comment: Missing php open tag "<".

Comment: Well, that was an edit error here!

Comment: Any useful information in the apache error.log file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add some code to show errors if any :

```
$db_connection = pg_connect("
    host=localhost 
    dbname=postgres 
    user=postgres 
    password=postgres
") or die('Could not connect:' . pg_last_error());
```